# Can't setup Android NDK location in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I set default location for AndroidSDK and JDK, but I can't set location for Android NDK - the field is grayed out.

[image: Disabled NDK path editing]

I downloaded NDK to some folder, set up ANDROID_NDK_HOME and NDK_HOME vars. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download zip folder from the link
[NDK LINK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html)

Then Extract to the location of the drive
Set NDK path to the NDK option as shown in the above image
[image: NDK IMAGE]

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I can't have NDK in different directory? I can set it up in Android project, but not as default folder

Comment: Update: I used your way, folder is set, but I can change it ONLY in specific project, and not globally

Comment: Which os your using?

Comment: If windows add folder path to environment. Similarly how will set java path to windows environment

[Set Environment Path](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YmuR4aw9pM)

Hope it helps..

Comment: Where is above image mentioned in your text? what is name of the environment variable that supposed to add? also the button squared red in your "below image" is still disabled even if NDK is extracted in that folder.

Comment: Can you send the pic

Answer (score 1):

I needed to install NDK for my react-native project, but same I couldn't set it up in android studio because it was grayed out...

Here is what worked for me (based on [protossor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755086/protossor) answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943764/gradle-sync-failed-ndk-not-configured-download-it-with-sdk-manager)):

1. In android studio go to File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> and install NDK (Side by side)
   [image]
2. Set up the enviromental virables NDK_HOME and NDK_MODULE_PATH (in my case both: C:\Users\piotr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\23.0.7123448 )
3. Finally in app/build.gradle change ndkVersion for exactly the one u have installed. For me like this:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

It was grayed for me too.

I fixed the problem by adding the NDK location to my `local.properties` file, eg:

```
ndk.dir=/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670
```