Ho do i resolve xml error while using cordova
Getting below issue:

Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\Divine\Desktop\appTime\platforms\android\gradlew -b >C:\Users\Divine\Desktop\appTime\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug

In my xml code:
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</platform>

I have this there, the application builds successfully when i take out the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE blocks but fails otherwise.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40943764/gradle-sync-failed-ndk-not-configured-download-it-with-sdk-manager
